# From Windows Form Application to Windows Service

Tags: winforms, windows-services

I had developed a Windows form application, to monitor the system status (Locked / not). Now the problem is the application has to be started manually to record the status. I need to convert that **Form application to Windows Service**...I don't need to use any Third party software as Always Up, FireDeamon. I need to do this only by coding. Can any of you help me. Comments and Replies are appreciated. Thankx in advance.